# Фоновое сканирование в Netbeans 8

Tags: ide, java, netbeans

Добрый день.

Фоновое сканирование открываемого .war проекта в Netbeans 8 постоянно зависает на сканировании папки web, останавливаясь на 98%. При попытке остановить процесс нетбинс выдает ошибку.

Детальное описание проблемы: http://statistics.netbeans.org/analytics/exception.do?id=758049

Проблема проявляется как на java7, так и на java8. При тех же условиях Netbeans 7.3 осуществляет фоновое сканирование того же .war проекта за считанные секунды. Пробовал увеличивать память для 8-ки, высталяя    `-J-client -J-Xss32m -J-Xmx1024m -J-Xms128m -J-XX:PermSize=64m -J-XX:MaxPermSize=256m`.

Никаких доп. плагинов на Netbeans 8 не установлено. Машина - 2 ядерный ноут 2,4Гц, ОЗУ - 4Гб.

Из текста ошибки (Slow scanning in js) понятно, что зависает на сканировании JS файлов, общий объем папки web около 10 Мб.

У кого-нибудь возникала подобная проблема и есть ли способы ее решения?

Answer (score 1):

[Совет помог избавиться от данного "недуга"](http://blog.eney-solutions.com.ua/general/ide/netbeans-zavisanie-pri-fonovom-skanirovanii-proektov.html):

> Открываем файл /etc/netbeans.conf, который лежит в папке установки IDE. Добавляем в него следующее:

```
-J-client -J-Xms32m -J-Xmx384m -J-XX:PermSize=32m -J-XX:MaxPermSize=200m -J-Xverify:none 
-J-XX:CompileThreshold=100 -XX:+CompressedOOPS -XX:+AggressiveOpts -XX:+TieredCompilation 
-XX:+DoEscapeAnalysis -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -J-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -J-XX:+CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled
```

Comment: постарайтесь, пожалуйста, оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы.